# Data cleanup in python using and excel file

Tags: python, dataframe, for-loop, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to do some cleanup on python using an excel file.
I have a bunch of columns, but those of interest are: dat.columns=['H', 'Test', 'ProductNumber','PM', 'THNewHRequired','THRealignment',
'THRecommendedRealignement']
Basically, what I'm trying to do is for each row that the product number contains TH, I'll look at the columns 'ProductNumber' and 'Test' to perform a comparison:

1. if the value of row (row 'x' for example) in 'Test' is equal to the value of 'ProductNumber' column (that left part should have the same length as the row in 'Test'), then I'll assign to column :
   . row 'x' of 'PM' column the 'PM' value of the corresponding row of ProductNumber column,
   . row 'x' of 'THRealignment' column the value 'Yes',
   .  row 'x' of 'THRecommendedRealignement' column, the value of column H of the corresponding row of ProductNumber column.
2. else, I'll assign to row 'x' of 'THNewHRequired' column the value 'Yes'.

In others words, for those rows that contains the 'TH' character, the columns THRecommendedRealignement, THRealignment, 'THNewHSKURequired', which are initially empty, have to be filled according the 1. statement or the 2. statement.

What I want to do is: if I have row1 in column Test, I want to compare that row1 with all the  rows of ProductNumber so that if there is a match, I apply statement 1.; if not, I will apply statement 2. Then I will follow by row 2 of column Test till row n of column Test.

I wrote the code below in jupyter notebook but it doesn't seems to be working. There is no error message, it's just that I don't get the desired resulted. Normally the columns (THRecommendedRealignement and THRealignment) or ('THNewHSKURequired') should be filled wherever the product number contains 'TH'. But after running the code, the dat frame remains the same, with no changes at all

```py
for product in dat['ProductNumber']:
    if "|TH" in dat['ProductNumber']:
        j=0
        for test in dat["Test"]:
            k=0
            for product in dat['ProductNumber']:
                if test[j]==product[k]:
                    dat['THRecommendedRealignement'][j]=dat['H'][k]
                    dat['THRealignment'][j]='Yes'
                    dat['PM'][k]=dat['PM'][j]
                else:
                    dat['THNewHSKURequired']='Yes'
                k+=1
            j+=1
```

[input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4j6U5.png)

So if we have this input, the output should be the image below. Note that the highlighted rows are the ones that should have been modified by the code.
[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B8wYM.png)

Comment: what error message do you get?

Comment: there is no error, it's just that i don't get the desired resulted. Normally the columns (THRecommendedRealignement and THRealignment) or ('THNewHSKURequired') should be filled wherever the product number contains 'DOH'.

Comment: `it doesn't seems to be working.` is the most useless information. We can't run code and see what get and we can't read in your mind - you have to describe all details. And you could create minimal working code with example data - and you could show what output you get and what output you expected. And put all information in question, not in commend - they will be more readable and more people will see it.

Comment: first you could use `print()` to see what you have in variables and which line of code is executed - it is called `"print debuging"`. It helps to see what code is really doing.